# Changing style in JS and changing style in CSS leads to different results

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

When I define the style of a divider using CSS, the output is this (green cell takes up the entire row ):
[image: screenshot]

When I define the style of a divider using JS, the output is this: Small green cube
[image: screenshot]

Why are the results different despite the code essentially doing the same things?

JS version

```js
    function App() {
      return (
        <div class = "App" >
          <div display = "flex" flexDirection = "row" flex = "1">
            <div class = "cell"></div>
          </div>
        </div>     
       );
    }
```

CSS version

```js
    function App() {
      return (
        <div class = "App" >
          <div class = "row-container">
            <div class = "cell"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
       );
    }
```

CSS code

```css
    .App {
      text-align: center;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    
    .row-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex: 1;
      /*justify-content: flex-center;*/
    }
    .row-container1 {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex: 1;
      /*justify-content: flex-center;*/
    }
    .cell {
      flex: 1; 
    
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 10px;
    
      background-color: green;
      border: 1px solid red;
      text-align: center;
    
    }
```

Comment: You should inspect your element to see applied styles on that element, and then you can tell what's different

Comment: Looks like only the CSS version has flex-grow on the flex child

Comment: @ZachJensz, can you elaborate?

Comment: `flex: 1` with one value is a [shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) for flex-grow. You only specify the flex grow on the child in the CSS version, and not the JS version.

Comment: @ZachJensz , the child has class "cell" in both cases. So I don't see the difference? I'm confused by the use of "class=" in the jsx, which should be a syntax error. That should be "className=" in the jsx.